# Does the Dread Curse of Azathoth spell stay active for multiple monsters?

Tags: arkham-horror

The spell says

> Cast and exhaust to gain +9 to Combat checks until the end of this combat.

Does the spell last until the end of combat with the current monster, or the end of combat for this turn, i.e. when I have 3 monsters on my street location and am fighting them. The wording seems to imply the end of the single current monster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the base rules:

> Whenever an investigator enters combat with a monster, resolve the following steps, in order.

You enter combat separately with each monster. "Combat" refers to that set of steps (horror check, fight or flee, monster damage). So no, it doesn't stay active for multiple monsters, and yes, "this combat" means combat with a single monster.